# How to make directives work on elements I insert into the DOM later?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to conditionally apply `ng-disabled` to an element that is enclosed by a controller but does not exists at time of original compile. It is created later on by an AJAX callback and needs to be enabled/disabled based on certain conditions. I guess it needs a directive, but how do I go about it?

I need to use `ng-disabled` and no other solution as it is well handled by IE<11, which do not support pointer-events.

---

The real code is too complicated to be quoted here, but let me rephrase the problem.
A jQuery lib does something like:

```
$.get(url, function(){
  $('<a class="btn"/>').appendTo(myDiv)
});
```

`myDiv` is within an angular controller. The `<a/>` element does not exist at time of compilation/directive linkage. Right after it gets appended, I should call some code to test and apply `ng-disabled` condition. Should it be a directive or a watch?

Comment: `$compile` it to have angular parse it and bind it to a scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a directive with an `ngIf` (so that it's created just when `ngIf` condition equals `true`. You can enable this condition after the response returns). Then in the link function you could:

```
link: function( scope, element, attrs ){
     element.removeAttr("name-of-the-directive");
     element.attrs("ng-disabled", "{{myExpression}}");
     $compile( element)(scope);



}
```

The line `element.removeAttr("name-of-the-directive");` is necessary to avoid infinite compiling loop.

Answer (score 0):

When you're inserting code into the DOM manually, you need to [compile it and link it to your scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) first.

---

If your use-case allows it, you could try using [ng-bind-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) in your template and then just put the loaded code into a `$scope` property without needing to `$compile` it yourself.